# Should I trust htop or top when it comes to RES memory?

Tags: linux, memory, top, htop

I am writing a program to test some memory usage metrics on our systems and I want to hit a target memory consumption. You execute my program via `meminflate.exe -G 103.1` if you want to take up `103.1 GB` of memory.

When I run `meminflate.exe -G 63.3`, I see top shows `VIRT` as `63.5` (OK, not too far off), but `RES` shows `63` on `top` and it shows `63.5` on `htop`. Which of these should I trust? I expect that `htop` is correct, but I wonder why there is a difference there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the exact number of bytes for Rss (resident set) from `/proc/<pid>/stat`:

```
echo $(($(cat /proc/$(pgrep -n meminflate.exe)/stat | cut -d' ' -f24)*4096))
```

To explain: this reads `/proc/<pid>/stat` (here the PID number is found using `pgrep`), the uses `cut` to only select the 24th field (Rss). Then the result is multiplied by 4096 (the normal page size on Linux). You can also only multiply it by 4 to get the size in kiB or divide it by 256 to get it in MiB.